# PHP ERROR Cant send data from form to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to do it in 2 ways. I use bootstrap on html and php to send data to the DB. Before posting I carefully read stackoverflow and try everything that I find in google. Please help, I new to php and really want to learn it, but this trouble gets me more than a 3 hours for this moment. Sorry for my bad English(for the case, im not from India)
First variant.
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Landing Page template</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="container-full">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center">

          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <p class="lead"><u>Sign-up and receive.</u></p>
          <p class="lead">No ads, no paid scum. No Bullshit.</p>
          <br><br><br>

          <form class="col-lg-12" action="dbconnection.php" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:340px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" title="Don't worry. We hate spam, and will not share your email with anyone." placeholder="Your email" type="text" name="name">
              <span class="input-group-btn" >
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"  type="submit"  
      name="submit" value=" Send">SUBMIT</button></span>

            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div> 
      <div class="row text-center v-center">
       <p class="lead">We Deliver: </p>


      </div>
      <!-- /row -->





    <!-- script references -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// connect to the database
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "emails";
$host_name = "localhost";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","emails") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($con));
//check connection
$name222 = $_POST["name"];
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$name')");
echo"record added";
$result = mysqli_query();
if($result){

    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");

} else{

    echo("<br>Input data is fail");

}
echo "Connection opened";

mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

ERRORS:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on line 12 record
>   added Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given
>   in C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on line 14
>
> Input data is failConnection opened Warning: mysql_close() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, object given in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on line 26

Second variant:
HTML:
same
PHP:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "emails";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
mysql_select_db("$database");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$order = "INSERT INTO emails

        (email)

        VALUES

        ('$name')";


$result = mysql_query($order);

if($result){

    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");

} else{

    echo("<br>Input data is fail");

}


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

errORS:

> Warning: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be
>   established in C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on
>   line 12
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO) in C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on
>   line 24
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in C:\OpenServer\domains\landing-cpa\dbconnection.php on line 24
>
> Input data is failConnected successfully

Comment: That is an awful lot of code, and I'm not very willing to read it all. Could you edit your question to contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: An awful lot of messy code, not even sure where to begin, but you should look at the cues the logs are providing you.  You have no password for a password-based mysql login, you're missing the connection variable in mysqli_query() - which even if you had the connection var in there would fail because of the previous failed connection. mysql_close() is failing because of the missing password.  put in a password and follow the error trail and you'll be happy.

Comment: hello, yes, its full code. I have no password in phpmyadmin, login root and no password at all, Before I post my question I changed pass, but still got errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, just reading about mysqli_real_escape_string here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

And get a working solution
Main error was in my syntax (mysql_string commands), code below totally works, mb It will help somebody in da future:

```
   <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","huj","huj","emails");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);


$sql="INSERT INTO emails (email)
VALUES ('$firstname')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```